# How can i use a pre installed Intellij Idea that was installed on Windows 7 now on linux?

Tags: linux, windows, intellij-idea, installation, operating-system

I have a pre-installed IntelliJ IDEA 2018 with all my code running on it on Windows 7.
I want to somehow use the same version of the installation instead of reinstalling the software again on linux and setting up all the libraries and the paths to my code again.

Is there a way that i can use that installation of IntelliJ on Windows in linux, too?

I have the software installed in D: Drive.

Comment: No, it is not possible, If you want to export your IDEA settings from windows to Linux installation use File | Export settings / File | Import settings options or Settings sync plugin. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, i had to go through a separate installation for linux and then import settings by using  setting sync plugin https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html